# Verification of Limit Proof for $\lim_{x \to 9} \sqrt{x-5} = 2$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

I am trying to solve this question $\lim_{x \to 9} \sqrt{x-5} = 2$. If you could tell me if I am going about this the right way I'd appreciate it.

Given $\epsilon > 0$, Let $\delta =min(9,\epsilon)$

Given $0<|x-9|<\delta$

$|f(x)-L| = |\sqrt{x-5}-2| =\left|(\sqrt{x-5}-2) \cdot \frac{\sqrt{x-5}+2}{\sqrt{x-5}+2}\right| = \left|\frac{x-9}{\sqrt{x-5}+2}\right|< \frac{\delta}{1}=\epsilon$

Note: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-5}+2}$ is always less than $\frac{1}{1}$

Does this make sense and is there a better way than doing this? Whenever I see a limit proof question with a root like this, my go-to approach is to multiply by the conjugate, is that the best approach?

Thanks

Comment: Nitpick: $\left|\sqrt{x-5}-2 \cdot \frac{\sqrt{x-5}+2}{\sqrt{x-5}+2}\right|$ should be $\left|\left( \sqrt{x-5}-2 \right)\cdot \frac{\sqrt{x-5}+2}{\sqrt{x-5}+2}\right|$.

Comment: Fixed, thank you

Comment: I would add that if $x \to 9$, then you can assume that $x \in (6,10)$.  This implies that $\sqrt{x - 5} + 2 \in (3,4)$, so that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-5} -2} \in \left( \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{3}\right)$.  Also, where do you use that $\delta = \min(5,\epsilon)$?

Comment: 5 is a natural restriction on $\delta$ because of the root and $\epsilon$ is the choice made for $\delta$. Also, so you want to assume that $\delta <1$ but regardless, we know that $\sqrt{x-5}+2$ is always greater than one anyways, so the fraction will always be less than one, so do we have to make that assumption? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: It should be $\delta=min(9,\epsilon)$ to reflect the natural restriction of the root, I changed it accordingly.

Comment: You're right about $\sqrt{x+5} + 2 \geq 2$, so ignore my previous comment there.